# Exporting Result Set to Another Table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can you export a result set given by a query to another table using SQL Server 2005?

I'd like to accomplish this without exporting to CSV?

Comment: What code have you got so far? Is a stored procedure involved somehow? Edit your question to give a bit more context.

Comment: My assumption was that "another table" didn't already exist. Can you clarify whether the other table exists, and can you better define "a query"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into table(column1, columns, etc) select columns from sourcetable
```

You can omit column list in insert if columns returned by select matches table definition. Column names in select are ignored, but recommended for readability.

Select into is possible too, but it creates new table. It is sometimes useful for selecting into temporary table, but be aware of tempdb locking by select into.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable(Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM SourceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
INTO dbo.newtable
FROM (SELECT ...query...) AS x;
```